# C++ Why the simplest loop addition displayed so slow in console?

Tags: c++

This might be trivial, but I can't find an answer. I know that my Intel i7 8 core processor can calculate millions of millions of bits per second.

However, the console is showing the following simple code at a much slower pace. In the console, it goes already fast but it takes some time to get to the end.

Is this because MS fixed the refreshing speed of the win32 console windows? Thank you in advance!

```
for(int i=1; i<=10e8;i++){
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

Comment: it takes time to display 100 million lines on a  console window . What were you expecting?

Comment: This is because the console is visible on the screen. Minimize the console window, count to three (OK, maybe to thirty three), and restore it again. The program should finish by then :)

Comment: @MitchWheat I know that the calculation from CPU goes to the actual screen takes far more time. But it should still be blazing fast. I have the feeling that the console window is slow somehow.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It doesn't matter, even if you minimize the window, it still goes slow.

Comment: @lulumink It does, I routinely use this trick with my applications that produce a lot of text output. You can time it to compare for yourself (change 10E8 to something smaller so that the full-screen version completes in a sane amount of time).

Comment: Incidentally, you are comparing an `int` to a `double` literal in that loop, usually it isn't a good idea (if e.g. instead of 10e8 you wrote 10e10, on 32 bit machines you would have obtained an endless loop)

Comment: @MatteoItalia Oops, it's true! Thanks a lot for pointing out!

Answer (score 8):

The console is slow because of the need to scroll the text up the screen. Every time you write another line to the console, the image of the current content needs to scroll up - an operation that requires a lot of copying to animate smooth scrolling. That is why there's a slowdown.

You can speed the process up by hiding the console window: the implementation is smart enough to not waste its time on scrolling. Another trick is reducing the height of the console to fewer lines: the text starts scrolling a lot faster, because less information needs to be copied.

Comment: I also wonder if the console waits on the monitor's vertical sync.

Comment: Thank you for sharing some insight info. It's very good to know that!

Answer (score 4):

The slowdown comes from displaying the data; the console is just not optimized to display text at incredible speed - if you needed that you'd write a GUI application (or even use DirectX or whatever else if necessary).

Also, there's overhead associated to flushing the buffer at each iteration (`endl` is equivalent to `\n` + `flush`, which means that you perform a `WriteFile` system call at each iteration - thus going in kernel mode), but it's usually secondary when writing on the console (where the output is line buffered anyway).

Comment: Thank you for the info. I didn't know this stuff at all! This really helps!